# FiniteDifferenceDerivative of complex function in 2D--bug?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, complex, finite-difference-method

I want to compute partial derivatives of complex functions via finite difference approximation on two dimensional grid using `` NDsolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative `` function (I'm on V10 on OSX). Let construct a discrete, rectangular grid $(x_i, y_j)$, $i=1,\ldots,n_x$, $j=1,\ldots,n_y$

```
xg = Range[-2, 2, 0.1];
yg = Range[-2, 2, 0.025];
{nx, ny} = Length/@{xg, yg};
xyg = Flatten[Outer[List, xg, yg], 1];
```

for which we create `FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction`'s

```
Do[FiniteDifferenceDerivative[i, j] = 
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[i, j], {xg, yg}, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 4], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}];
```

Let's take simple nontrivial example

```
f = Function[{x, y}, Cos[x*y] + I*Sin[x*y]];
```

Calculating $\partial_{x}f$ gives reasonable result. Problematic is $\partial_{y}f$

```
ListPlot3D[
 Flatten /@ 
  Transpose@{xyg, 
    Re@Flatten[
      FiniteDifferenceDerivative[0, 1][Partition[f @@@ xyg, ny]]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

For comparison we can plot analytic expression for $\partial_{y}f$

```
 Plot3D[Re@Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

I've checked that this gives incorrect result for complex functions only. Another interesting thing is that `FiniteDifferenceDerivative[0, 1][Partition[f @@@ xyg, ny]]` seems to generate random results, compare

[image]

with previous plot. The quesiton is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong? Is this OS or *Mathematica* version (and so `NDSolve` version) dependent issue? One possible resolution is to take out differentiation matrices from `FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction` object and apply them by hand (I thought this is what is done when `FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction` is called, please correct me if I'm wrong), eg.

```
Transpose @ Dot[
  FiniteDifferenceDerivative[0, 1][[3, 2, 1]],
   Transpose @ Partition[f @@@ xyg, ny]]
```

to get $\partial_yf$ (the result can be plotted as before with `ListPlot3D[Flatten /@ Transpose@{xyg, Re @ Flatten @ %}, PlotRange -> All]`), but is this the only way to get correct result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in 10.0 up to 10.2. According to reply to my report [CASE:3484187]

> The issue has been resolved in version 10.3. Please upgrade.

I hope this will be helpful to someone.